# Hadoop Configuration Error

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am attempting to start up my hadoop application, however upon startup i am seeing this in the log files, does anyone have a clue as to what the problem is?

> Creating filesystem for hdfs://10.170.4.141:9000
>       java.io.IOException: config()
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.(Configuration.java:229)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.(Configuration.java:216)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.(SecurityUtil.java:60)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.makeSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:188)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:168)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:198)
>           at   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:88)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1413)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:68)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1431)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:256)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:125)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:240)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
>           at  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.addInputPath(FileInputFormat.java:372)
>           at org.blismedia.VolumeReportGenerateUpdates.main(VolumeReportGenerateUpdates.java:156)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)

Comment: have you explicitly specified the machine's ip address  as input/output ? It owuld help if you could share your `config()` also how are you giving in[put/output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're running into [HADOOP-2851](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-2851). This "error" can safely be ignored.

Apparently, Configuration's constructor logs an exception to the debug log, despite no exception actually being thrown. Why? Your guess is as good as mine. But the issue is resolved in their project as won't fix. "It's a feature, not a bug."

```
public Configuration(boolean loadDefaults) {
  if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
    LOG.debug(StringUtils.stringifyException(new IOException("config()")));
  }
  // ...
}
```